# Обменять значения массива

Tags: ассемблер, masm

В регистрах `eax` и `ebx` содержатся два 32-битных положительных целых числа, в `edx` - указатель на 1-ый элемент массива таких чисел. Как за наименьшее количество инструкций обменять значения `[edx + eax * 4]` и `[edx + ebx * 4]` массива?

Доступны команды `intel x86, Windows`.

Answer (score 1):

Гм...

```
    mov  ecx, dword ptr [edx+eax*4]
    xchg ecx, dword ptr [edx+ebx*4]
    mov  dword ptr [edx+eax*4], ecx
```